# Unresolved external simbol b3Clock

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, clock, bulletphysics

I'm getting the famous error LNK 2019. I've been reading a lot of info about it. However, I'm not able to solve my problem:

I have a **.cpp** with this includes:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GraphicSettings.h"
```

And in **GraphicSetting.h**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "../3rd-party/bullet3-2.86/examples/Utils/b3Clock.h"
```

Everything seems to work fine but whenever I try to compile...

[image: LNK ERROR]

Reading solutions, I finally *Add* b3Clock.cpp to my project, but the error stills appearing.

[image]

What am I doing bad?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you link the bullet lib with your project ?

"Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories"
and "Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies"

Comment: Yes I did. I'm attempting to use one of the examples codes (the one that's called AppExampleGUI) in order to make my application graphical. Bullet is working as expected, the graphical engine no.

Comment: The fact was that the code was out of every other Bullet project. So when I added the references, it makes no effect. What I finally did is to copy the .cpp and .h files in my project and include them as proper files. I don't know if this is the best solution but it solve my problem.